# How to make an element change its font-size on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nav bar brand element that I would like to make smaller after a user scrolls down on my page.

```
<a class="navbar-brand color" href="home.html">Brand</a>
```

I have the navbar-brand.color set to:

```
font-size:60px;
```

When user scrolls down, I would like it to automatically shift to 40px.

How can this be done?

Comment: `window.onscroll = function(){ document.querySelector('.navbar-brand color').style.fontSize = '40px'};`

Comment: Tresdin, how do I make it activate further down the scroll and not on an immediate scroll?

Comment: You need to be more clear about the requirement. How much further down do you want? 200px? 500px?

Comment: I would recommend you have him animate it, too. ;)

Comment: Tresdin, about 500px after the initial scroll.

Comment: Tresdin, do you think you can put an answer using pure javascript, on how you would change the font after a 500px scroll down?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with specific `font-size` you wan to add
For example

```
.scrollFontSize{
   font-size:60px;
}
```

With jquery add the class on scrolling

```
   $('body').on('scroll', 'someDom', function() {
  // will give position of scrollbar
  var height = $(this).scrollHeight();
  if (height > someDesiredValue) {
    // this will update the font size
    $('.navbar-brand').addClass('scrollFontSize')
  } else if (height === 0) {
    // removing specific font size on scrolling back to top
    $('.navbar-brand').removeClass('scrollFontSize')
  }

})
```

Comment: What if you wanted to do this in pure javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the required scrollTop value is reached on scroll and then apply the font size.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  //var height = any value
  if($(this).scrollTop >= height)
    $(".navbar-brand color").css("font-size","40px");
  else
    $(".navbar-brand color").css("font-size","60px");
});
```

Comment: Can you add to this code how you would do it in pure javascript?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to animate the font size based on the scroll you may want to try **[this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vL0bramc/)**

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    //.05 is a multiplier for the font size
    //14 is the default font size
    $('p').css('font-size',(($(this).scrollTop()*.05)+14)+'px');
});
```

**Pure Javascript**
This is the same thing done in pure javascript **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vL0bramc/1/)**

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
  document.querySelector('p').style.fontSize=((document.body.scrollTop*.05)+14)+'px';
});
```

Comment: Can you add to this code how you would do it in pure javascript?